# Steps involved in simplifying trigonometric identities.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to master the simplification of trigonometric identities. When I look at a problem, asking me to simplify a trigonometric expression, I am not really sure what to do - but I do sort of understand what is happening when I look at the solution.

Is their a list of official 'steps' I need to follow? Like should I try and put everything to one type of ratio? this is quite an ambiguous problem, which is but a reflection of my poor understanding of this whole ordeal.

I never really know what to do, and nothing makes sense. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Give a sample example which You can't understand, and help shall be there!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849336/basic-trigonometry-identities-question/849488#849488 may be helpful.